How to start Hazelcast management center?
I ran these commands in 3 different CMD:
docker run -it --network hazelcast-network --rm -e HZ_CLUSTERNAME=hello-world -p 5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast:5.3.0
docker run -it --network hazelcast-network --rm -e HZ_CLUSTERNAME=hello-world -p 5702:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast:5.3.0
docker run -it --network hazelcast-network --rm -e HZ_CLUSTERNAME=hello-world -p 5703:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast:5.3.0

I changed the cluster-name in hazelcast.xml and hazelcast-client.xml to "hello-world".
And I ran this command from the bin folder:
./hz-cli.bat -f="C:\Users\Mikail\Downloads\hazelcast-5.3.0\hazelcast-5.3.0\config\hazelcast-client.xml" console
Then when I try to ran management center with this command:
java -jar hazelcast-management-center-5.3.0.jar
I get this error:
2024-06-06 00:01:34,293 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.MCApplication]: Starting MCApplication v5.3.0 using Java 22.0.1 on DESKTOP-TSMVM22 with PID 28432 (C:\Users\Mikail\Downloads\hazelcast-5.3.0\hazelcast-5.3.0\management-center\hazelcast-management-center-5.3.0.jar started by Mikail in C:\Users\Mikail\Downloads\hazelcast-5.3.0\hazelcast-5.3.0\management-center)
2024-06-06 00:01:34,304 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.MCApplication]: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-06-06 00:01:36,592 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.c.SqlDbConfig]: Checking DB for required migrations.
2024-06-06 00:01:37,130 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.c.SqlDbConfig]: Number of applied DB migrations: 0.
2024-06-06 00:01:38,012 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.m.i.r.RocksDBLoader]: 'C:\Users\Mikail\AppData\Local\Temp\' is used as RocksDB shared library directory
2024-06-06 00:01:38,170 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.m.i.r.RocksDBLoader]: 'C:\Users\Mikail\AppData\Local\Temp\' is used as RocksDB shared library directory
2024-06-06 00:01:38,325 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.s.s.i.DisableLoginStrategy]: Login will be disabled for 5 seconds after 3 failed login attempts. For every 3 consecutive failed login attempts, disable period will be multiplied by 10.
2024-06-06 00:01:39,303 [ WARN] [main] [o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext]: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'phoneHomeService' defined in class path resource [com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/telemetry/PhoneHomeConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'phoneHomeService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'phoneHomeDataFactory' defined in class path resource [com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/telemetry/PhoneHomeConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'phoneHomeDataFactory' parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceDataTracker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping bean class com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.telemetry.InstanceData didn't find any matching columns in result set
2024-06-06 00:01:39,362 [ERROR] [main] [o.s.b.SpringApplication]: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'phoneHomeService' defined in class path resource [com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/telemetry/PhoneHomeConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'phoneHomeService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'phoneHomeDataFactory' defined in class path resource [com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/telemetry/PhoneHomeConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'phoneHomeDataFactory' parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceDataTracker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping bean class com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.telemetry.InstanceData didn't find any matching columns in result set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar!/:2.7.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar!/:2.7.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar!/:2.7.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar!/:2.7.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar!/:2.7.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar!/:2.7.11]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.MCApplication.main(MCApplication.java:56) ~[classes!/:5.3.0]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[hazelcast-management-center-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[hazelcast-management-center-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[hazelcast-management-center-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[hazelcast-management-center-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'phoneHomeDataFactory' defined in class path resource [com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/telemetry/PhoneHomeConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'phoneHomeDataFactory' parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceDataTracker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping bean class com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.telemetry.InstanceData didn't find any matching columns in result set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        ... 25 more

How can I solve this problem?
I also try to run "mc-start" but same error.

I suggest using the hz-mc start command, as documented in the manual. Also the latest version is 5.4.1 , in case you face any problems, you can try upgrading.
